# The structure of $PSL_2$ over the p-adic integers

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

As is well known, the group $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{Z})$ is isomorphic to the free product of two cyclic groups of orders 2 and 3.

Is there a similar description of the projective special linear group over p-adic integers? If yes, where can I find it? If no, what is known about the algebraic structure of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{Z}_p)$? Where to find it?

Comment: It's a profinite, actually virtually pro-$p$ and $p$-adic analytic group, so reading about such topological groups might be helpful. Even as an abstract group, it doesn't split as a nontrivial free product or even amalgam.

Comment: Building on @YCor's comment, there is an abstract characterization of $p$-adic analytic groups (so the kernel $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)\to PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$) as $p$-powerful groups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_p-group

Comment: Well $PSL(2,\mathbf{Z}_p)$ itself is $p$-adic analytic but not pro-$p$ and the characterization is among pro-$p$-groups (which is fine since a $p$-adic analytic profinite group is virtually pro-$p$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any book/article suggestions for learning virtually pro-$p$ and $p$-adic analytic groups?
@YCor: Is there an easy way to see why  $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{Z}_p)$ doesn't split as a nontrivial free product/amalgam.